# How could publishers, in particular disreputable ones, prove that you “signed” a copyright agreement?

Tags: paper-submission, copyright, legal-issues, disreputable-publishers

With almost every question from people having dealing with predatory publishers, the question comes up whether they have already signed a copyright agreement. This always makes me ask myself this question:

**When it comes to that point, how could a publisher actually prove, that you “signed” a specific copyright transfer agreement?** Any copyright transfer agreement I have encountered so far (only reputable publishers) I agreed to by clicking on a button in some submission system. Now there are two cases to distinguish:

- The submission system is hosted by a third party. In this case, the publisher has a source other than itself that could confirm that you¹ clicked on *agree* and what exactly you agreed to. I do not deny that there may be some evidence here.
- The system is hosted by the publisher itself. Some reputable publishers do this (at least so it seems to me) and I also would guess that this is what most disreputable publishers do. How can the publisher produce any evidence that you¹ clicked the button and what copyright agreement was shown to you? They can show that the `accepted_copyright_agreement`-flag in their database is set to `true` for your submission, but given that it’s their database, they can manipulate it at will and this does not constitute any proof.

I have not come across any other case where such kind of unilateral agreements are made online. For example, if I buy something online, the actual contract of sale is established by me transferring money (or similar) and the other party transferring a product (and I have full return rights for some weeks, at least in my country, legal disputes on whether the *buy* button was actually clicked are unlikely).

Note that I am not so much asking about whether some evidence would actually convince a court but rather about anything that could be even considered as evidence by any reasonable person or court.

---

<sup>¹ or more precisely: the person who submitted the manuscript</sup>

Comment: If your question is really "what is the legal status of ...", then it is straight off-topic. Different thing would be asking, "what are the true consequences of you claiming you didn't sign the copyright". That would be fine in my opinion.

Comment: @yo': I don’t think that the question after the legal status would be off-topic, but rather unanswerable for lack of specific laws or precedence cases. Anyway, that’s not my question. My question is rather whether there is anything which is conceivable to have some noteworthy legal status in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would like to clear up a little misconception. A signature is never proof of anything. There is very little difference among a hand written signature, pressing the I agree button, and writing an 'X' on the signature line. They all carry the exact same legal weight provided they were done in a proper fashion. The only time a signature is ever really sufficient proof is when it has been notarized (which is much more than just the notary's signature). So, signing a paper and faxing it over, for instance, doesn't have much more value then pressing your "I agree" button. Without being notarized, signatures in any form are simply evidence.

Third parties, in this case, can effectively act as notaries to a certain extent. There tend to be very strict guidelines when dealing with electronic signatures. Depending on the field and the government involved, how the signatures are stored is often very important. Other than the legal requirements, the person or court would need to ask the question "Why would the third party forge the signature" and "Was the signer who they say they were". Usually these are emailed and involve a unique token, so identity is based on the security of email and the token is stored and hopefully not accessed. Periodic backups (using non-re-writable media) that are stored securely can often be used to ensure data hadn't been added or modified.

It is nearly impossible for a party of the deal to serve as the sole witness to the authenticity of any signature as they generally have reason to lie. Instead, they need to show that you agreed to transfer copyright as evidence that the signature is authentic. If they don't have you agreeing to the publication somewhere, then they are just waving around a piece of paper with an 'X' on it.

Comment: What do you mean in practice by "they need to show that you agreed to transfer copyright as evidence that the signature is authentic"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I apologize if that was confusing. The publisher needs to show that an agreement actually took place in some way external to that signature. For instance, they can show that you submitted a final draft to the journal for publication. They can show that as part of their process, all other articles published saw the same form to transfer copyright.  This is evidence (not necessarily substantive enough) that authenticates the signature.

Comment: @WilliamForcier: (1) *For instance, they can show that you submitted a final draft to the journal for publication.* – How would they do this without encountering exactly the same problem? (2) *They can show that as part of their process, all other articles published saw the same form to transfer copyright.* – Do you mean by producing people as witnesses who published an article at a similar time?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft (1) I was suggesting something along the lines of pulling email correspondences through things like gmail or a university email. Though, email is not necessarily 'secure'. (2) Yeah, something like that. Basically, they are trying to show that their process exists. Obviously you could be the only one they fooled, but it is probably more likely that there would be others. Was this single article really worth jail time to the journal?

Answer (score 0):

The standard in US civil courts is that one side needs to show by a [preponderance of the evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_burden_of_proof#Preponderance_of_the_evidence) that their side is true. This is actually a pretty low bar, i.e. that there's a greater than 50% chance that their version is true. It's a lot easier to come up with evidence to this level than it is to the "reasonable doubt" standard that US criminal prosecutions need in order to convict some one of a crime.

As such, a copy of the email from your email address, attested to by sworn testimony from the recipient and containing the proper text to be a copyright transfer would probably be sufficient. Similar evidence could be used if you submitted the form through a website. In order to rebut this evidence you'd need convincing evidence that you didn't do it or that it was done fraudulently.

I know that you say that you don't care about what a court would say, but the only time it would come up is in that context. Nothing else matters. If you need to try to stop someone from publishing an article or to retract an already published one, in the end, you're going to be in court. If you're going to try to convince a judge or jury that you didn't really execute the copyright transfer, you're going to have a high hurdle. If the journal presents some evidence of a transfer document, you're going to have to try to convince a judge/jury that it's somehow fraudulent.

Comment: 1) I did not say that I do not care about what a court would say. I only said that I am more interested in the existence of evidence than in its potential effectiveness in court. 2) *As such, a copy of the email from your email address, attested to by sworn testimony from the recipient and containing the proper text to be a copyright transfer would probably be sufficient.* – While I agree that an e-mail, whose existence can be confirmed by a third party, is evidence, I fail to see what the recipient’s testimony be good for as the recipient is the publisher.

Comment: 3) *Similar evidence could be used if you submitted the form through a website.* – But what should this evidence look like? That’s the central point of my question: How could a publisher not using an external sumbmission system produce any evidence that I clicked a button in this system? 4) *If the journal presents some evidence of a transfer document, you're going to have to try to convince a judge/jury that it's somehow fraudulent.* – But only if there is some evidence (that remotely deserves to be called such) in the first place. And where such evidence comes from, is exactly my question.

Comment: Testimony from a person at the publisher that they received your email of the copyright transfer agreement and a copy of that agreement is sufficient evidence. If they go to court and swear to that, unless you get on the stand and swear that you didn't, they don't have to do anything else. One of you is lying. At that point, they can try to produce further details from their email (or webserver or whatever) logs that show further evidence of receipt. They can also subpoena your computer, your ISP, etc, to produce *your* records. They can produce the history of your interaction.

Comment: Presumably when you fill out the web form saying you'd like to transfer the copyright, that's part of a system that you logged in to. You submitted your article through it, gave them contact information, etc. All of that info is part of a database, presumably, that keeps a coherent record. The designer of the system can testify to its design and produce records related to your interaction with it. At that point, it's up to you to rebut their evidence. Maybe you were in Bora Bora snorkeling on the day the claim you transferred the copyright, and you can prove it. That's evidence the other way.

Comment: @BillBarth still, I, as an editor of a shady journal, can sign up in your name with your email, pull the password from the DB (by default I generate four digits codes, so I can also crack it), and sign in. The IP will be off, but they are known to change, and the rest will be consistent.

Comment: @Davidmh, yeah, and? So when I call you to the stand when I'm suing you in court for fraudulently publishing my paper, I'll have subpoenaed your records for that IP info and use it to impeach your testimony. I'll also have the opportunity to testify that I was on an airplane or teaching class at the time your records indicate. That won't be good for your case. You guys seem to be beating up a strawman here. Unscrupulous publishers aren't going to sweat the lack of a proper copyright transfer, and they're going to publish your article from a jurisdiction that's hard for you to get to anyway.

Comment: @BillBarth: 1) In the usual situation where the author does not dispute having interacted with the journal’s submission system (e.g., they submitted the paper, did not transfer copyright and retracted after shady reviews came in two days later), all your proposed evidence is worthless. 2) I am not necessarily talking about the author suing the publisher but about the possibility of the publisher suing the author (that is often implicitly considered in such questions) – whether that’s a realistic thing to happen or not.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, In your example, the onus will be on the pub to show you transferred, and if their evidence is weak, they will probably lose. Many of the things I listed would be fine evidence (on a plane, in class, wrong IP, etc). I think the most likely situation is that you would have to sue them after being turned down for publication by a second publisher who sees their fraudulent publication as having already published your article. I also think this is pretty unlikely. You didn't pay, and you demanded a retraction. The shady publishers want your money waaay more than your article.

Comment: It should be noted that although this dispute may have some civil qualities, if the author is saying that they never signed a copyright agreement and the journal is saying that the author did, then the author is accusing the journal of forgery, a rather serious crime.

Comment: @WilliamForcier, good point. That's a 3rd degree felony in my state. I doubt any publisher who would get up to this scheme would be based in a country where you could easily go after them nor would they be likely to come after you.